# How to change List-Column from Hyperlink or Picture to Single line of text in Sharepoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have a column in a sharepoint list which is currently a Hyperlink or Picture. When I go to list setting and click on that column in order to change the type I don't see any such option. Is there any way we can change a Hyperlink to Single line of text, so that the item in that column is as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new column of Single line type
2. Copy values of items from your current column to a new column for ex. with powershell
3. Remove your current column.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use Powershell to copy items with in the same list.